# Magento adding install object

Tags: php, object, attributes, magento, installation

I'm creating a module that let's you define some extra options for categorys in Magento, following this tuturial to get started: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module

I built on a skeleton module created with ModuleCreator.

I have created Setup.php (with the capital) in **Infoweb/Margins/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/**
and in it my class defined:

```
class Infoweb_Margins_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup{}
```

I also added this line in my config.php(the rest was already there because of the skeleton module):

```
<class>Infoweb_Margins_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
```

Now when trying to load a page, magento searches for this class but gives a fatal error saying the class was not found ...
Error:
*Fatal error: Class 'Infoweb_Margins_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /home/users/A000456/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 160*

Thoughts on where the problem lies?

Using Magento 1.4.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is complaining that it can't find your class

```
Infoweb_Margins_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
```

this is actually semi-good news.  The fact that Magento knew to look for a class with the prefix Infoweb_Margins means you have your XML setup correctly.

The problem is your class name.  Magento's auto loader only* knows how to handle class in the form

```
Packagename_Modulename_Model_*
Packagename_Modulename_Helper_*
Packagename_Modulename_Block_*
```

your class is named

```
Infoweb_Margins_Resource_*
```

which Magento doesn't know what to do with.

If you've placed a file named Setup.php at

```
Infoweb/Margins/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/
```

you want a class named

```
Infoweb_Margins_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
```

Change that in your XML and class definition and you should be set

** this might be a semi-fib, I haven't peeked at Magento's __autoloader in a while*

Comment: Thanks, but I have 1 more question, how do I re-install the module? I only got it to add the attributes after importing an older database and then refreshing. Disabling the module didn't do it and I have all caches disabled.

Comment: Also, I can't get SCOPE_STORE to work, I can only add GLOBAL options(no checkbox on store view) :(

I really need to be able to set an attributes per store

Comment: Delete your module from the core_resources (if my memoery serves me right) table in the database. Magento will then re-run the install logic. 

You could also bump the version number.

Comment: Thank you, any idea about how to get SCOPE_STORE or SCOPE_WEBSITE to work? Currently using: 
'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,